# TextView is ListView is not shown correctly

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have an app that take strings from database and put it in ListView.
this is the code for getting my String from database:

```
    public void setLogView(String date){


    ArrayAdapter<TextView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    DataBaseMain dataBase = new DataBaseMain(this);
    dataBase.open();
    String[][] all = dataBase.dayLog(date);
    dataBase.close();

    if(all == null)
        return;

String temporay = "";

    for(int j = 0; j < all[0].length; j++){
            temporay = "";  
        for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            temporay = temporay + " " + all[i][j];
            text.setText(temporay);
            adapter.add((TextView)text);
            }
        }   
}
```

Its seems that i get new TextView in my ListView but the text is messed up.
I checked my `temporay` string and is fine.
Is somewhere in putting him in the ListView.
No error in logcat or exceptions.
here is what i got in my app ListView insted of my wanted text.(i wanted to put picutrue but i dont have enough repetion:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot what you are expecting ang what you observe

Comment: i added you reputation, so you can add a picture

Comment: Please add screenshot.

Comment: @CRUSADER. Added the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, it becomes clear from the image you provided

Try, this..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Your adapter to appending textView object instead of String you are providing.

then add temporay instead of textView inside you loop..like

```
 adapter.add(temporay);
```

This, will certainly solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter to `ArrayAdapter<String>`, and add `temporay` instead of the whole listview.

Or else, you can extend the ArrayAdapter in and override the `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, you are trying to display the text in custom listview using separate layout.xml which contains only textview in it.

Check my example given below, this is how i did to achieve this:

First of all fetch the data you are want to display and store it in an ArrayList. Here, `al_rec_id`, `al_rec_name` are arraylists of the type `Integer` and `String`, respectively.

```
cursor = database.query("records_data", new String[]{"rec_id", "rec_name"}, "cat_id=?", new String[]{cat_id+""}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    al_rec_id.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                    al_rec_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
```

After that, bind this arraylist with ArrayAdapter and then set this adapter to listview as below. Here, array_adapter_all_records  is an ArrayAdapter of the type String

```
array_adapter_all_records = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_row_home, R.id.textViewSingleRowHome, al_rec_name);
        listview_all_records.setAdapter(array_adapter_all_records);
```

This is my single_row_home.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSingleRowHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        style="@style/listview_only_textview"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thats it. And you're done...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class custom adapter which will extend your ArrayList Adapter in that You can either inflate a different xml which contains your textview or you can create a dynamic textview as you are doing it now in your getView method in custom Adapter. If You need an example let me know.